# referer content missing on request header on next.js getserverside props?

Tags: next.js, http-headers, server-side-rendering

While calling the API from next.js getserversideprops function. The request header does not contain the referer content. We have validation on backend based on the referer. how can I send it to the backend? Why the request header does not contain the referer?

[image]